# Issue with innerHTML of label in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to update label with text

```
var label_count2 = document.createElement("label");              
        label_count2.setAttribute("id", "label_count2");     
        label_count2.style.textAlign = "right";
        label_count2.style.border = "none"; 

gradient_div.appendChild(label_count2);            
self.parent.appendChild(gradient_div);

 updateText : function (text){

        document.getElementById("label_count2").innerHTML = count; 

    },
```

when I tried to call to `updateText()` the value in the screen didn't change.

I checked it in the debugger and I saw that the value is correct.

i tried to change the `innerHTML` To `innerText` and it also didn't work.

If I add line `label_count2.innerHTML = "any text"` then I can see the value.

Could you advise me why it is not working from the function ?

Comment: You can set the "id" as a property: `label_count2.id = "label_count2";`

Comment: What is `count` in the `updateText` function ? Shouldn't it be `text` ?

Comment: the ID is ok the issue is in the text

Comment: the count is text it is number

Comment: @user1365697 yes but the parameter to the function is called "text", not "count"

Comment: Your code is too incomplete to debug. Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: sorry it should be text , but it is not the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
self.parent.appendChild(gradient_div);
```

makes me think (though I can't be certain) that you're adding the element to the parent window.  If that's the case, then the `document` from the child window won't contain the element, so "getElementById()" will return `null`.

If that's the case, then:

```
  self.parent.document.getElementById('label_count2').innerHTML = count;
```

might work.

Comment: In the debbug i success to get result from document.getElementById("label_count2").innerText

Comment: Hmm OK well it's not at all clear what that "update_text" thing is supposed to be. It looks like you've posted just a fragment of the code.